# Add an additional line on the grid

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am looking for help, I hope I can solve this problem.

I've created a new screen and I'm filtering all the Revalue Accounts information.

With this screen, what I want to do is insert and at the same time add an additional new line within the grid.

Here is my new created screen and the button that inserts GLTran

[image]

I am attaching an image where I want the line to be added at insert time

[image]

Here I share code that I have and it does not work for the additional line.

```
   private void CreateDNGL(Batch batch)

    {
        var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<JournalEntry>();

        if (graph.BatchModule.Current == null)
        {
            Batch cmbatch = new Batch();

            cmbatch.BranchID = batch.BranchID;
            cmbatch.Module = batch.Module;
            cmbatch.Status = "U";
            cmbatch.AutoReverse = true;
            cmbatch.Released = true;
            cmbatch.Hold = false;
            cmbatch.CuryDebitTotal = batch.CuryDebitTotal;
            cmbatch.CuryCreditTotal = batch.CuryCreditTotal;
            cmbatch.FinPeriodID = batch.FinPeriodID;
            cmbatch.CuryID = batch.CuryID;
            cmbatch.CuryInfoID = batch.CuryInfoID;
            cmbatch.DebitTotal = batch.DebitTotal;
            cmbatch.CreditTotal = batch.CreditTotal;
            cmbatch.Description = "Head new insert";
            cmbatch = graph.BatchModule.Insert(cmbatch);
        }
        foreach (GLTran item in PXSelect<GLTran,
            Where<GLTran.module, Equal<Required<GLTran.module>>,
            And<GLTran.batchNbr, Equal<Required<GLTran.batchNbr>>>>>.Select(this, batch.Module, batch.BatchNbr))
        {
            GLTran tran = new GLTran();
            tran.SummPost = item.SummPost;
            tran.ZeroPost = false;
            tran.DebitAmt = item.DebitAmt;
            tran.CreditAmt = item.CreditAmt;
            tran.CuryDebitAmt = item.CuryDebitAmt;
            tran.CuryCreditAmt = item.CuryCreditAmt;
            tran.AccountID = item.AccountID;
            tran.SubID = item.SubID;
            tran.LineNbr = item.LineNbr;
            tran.LedgerID = item.LedgerID;
            tran.TranType = item.TranType;
            tran.TranClass = item.TranClass;
            tran.RefNbr = string.Empty;
            tran.FinPeriodID = item.FinPeriodID;
            tran.TranDesc = "Test detail";
            tran.Released = true;
            tran.ReferenceID = item.ReferenceID;
            tran = graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert(tran);

            Account account = PXSelect<Account, Where<Account.accountID,
       Equal<Required<Account.accountID>>>>.Select(graph, item.AccountID);
            xLocEquivalAcct equivalAcct = PXSelect<xLocEquivalAcct, Where<xLocEquivalAcct.acctCD,
                                   Equal<Required<xLocEquivalAcct.acctCD>>>>.Select(graph, account.AccountCD);

            if (equivalAcct != null)
            {
                /*here is added for an additional line*/
                var glTran = graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert();
                graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.accountID>(glTran, 343567);
                graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.subID>(glTran, 281);
                glTran.TranDesc = "add extra line";
                if (item.DebitAmt != 0m && item.CreditAmt == 0m)
                {
                    if (batch.Module == BatchModule.CM)
                    {
                        graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.curyDebitAmt>(glTran, item.CuryDebitAmt);
                        graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.debitAmt>(glTran, item.DebitAmt);
                    }
                }
                if (item.CreditAmt != 0m && item.DebitAmt == 0m)
                {
                    if (batch.Module == BatchModule.CM)
                    {
                        graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.curyCreditAmt>(glTran, item.CuryCreditAmt);
                        graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.creditAmt>(glTran, item.CreditAmt);
                    }
                }
                glTran = graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(glTran);
            }
        }
        graph.Save.Press();
    }
```

I hope I was clear with my question.

Answer (score 0):

This code will create a copy of the originating batch and insert additional lines.

#Warning Your original code was attempting to create a batch that was already released but unposted. I can update my answer to match your requirement but this will break Acumatica work-flow.

Please find code example below :

```
public class JournalEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<JournalEntry>
    {
        public PXAction<Batch> CopyCreate;

        //CommitChanges being set to false allows the graph to not be considered dirty when there are errors that we manually show on screen. Case #207998
        [PXButton(CommitChanges = false)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Copy Create", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update, Enabled = true)]
        protected virtual IEnumerable copyCreate(PXAdapter pxAdapter)
        {
            if (Base.BatchModule.Current != null)
            {
                if (Base.IsDirty)
                {
                    Base.BatchModule.Ask("You must discard your unsaved changes to be able to press this button.", MessageButtons.OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    Batch batch = Base.BatchModule.Current;

                    PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, () => CreateDNGL(batch));
                }
            }

            return pxAdapter.Get();
        }

        private static void CreateDNGL(Batch batch)
        {
            JournalEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<JournalEntry>();

            Batch newBatch = PXCache<Batch>.CreateCopy(batch);
            newBatch.NoteID = null;
            newBatch.Description = "Test header";
            newBatch = graph.BatchModule.Insert(newBatch);

            GLTran newTran;

            foreach (GLTran tran in PXSelectReadonly<GLTran,
            Where<GLTran.module, Equal<Required<GLTran.module>>,
            And<GLTran.batchNbr, Equal<Required<GLTran.batchNbr>>>>>.Select(graph, batch.Module, batch.BatchNbr))
            {
                newTran = PXCache<GLTran>.CreateCopy(tran);
                newTran.Module = null;
                newTran.BatchNbr = null;
                newTran.NoteID = null;
                newTran.TranDesc = "Test detail";
                newTran = graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert(newTran);
            }

            if (true)
            {
                newTran = graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert();
                newTran.AccountID = 1190;
                newTran.SubID = 467;
                newTran.CuryDebitAmt = 1000;
                newTran.TranDesc = "Additional Line 1";

                newTran = graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(newTran);

                newTran = graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert();
                newTran.AccountID = 1190;
                newTran.SubID = 467;
                newTran.CuryCreditAmt = 1000;
                newTran.TranDesc = "Additional Line 2";

                newTran = graph.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(newTran);
            }

            graph.Save.Press();
        }
    }
```

Original Batch :

[image: Original Batch]

New Batch :

[image: New Batch]